# Should I avoid references between worksheets in Excel to increase performance?

Tags: excel, performance, optimization

I'm building a large Excel workbook where many of the worksheets are going to have the same monthly timeline consisting of several rows of calculations spanning several decades (start of month, end of month, year, quarter, month ID, quarter ID, etc.). I was wondering if in this case it is preferable performance wise to only calculate the timeline in one worksheet and then simply reference those calculations across all the other worksheets - in order to only perform the calculations once. Or is it preferable to calculate the timeline data in every worksheet to avoid references between worksheets? The reason I ask is that some performance-related articles I've read mentioned that it is preferable to avoid links between worksheets to increase performance.

Comment: Excel formula only calculate if the data to which it refers changes.  So having the formula on the sheet would mean that it would calculate only if the information on the sheet changed.  Having it on one sheet and links(which depending on the type are just other formula) means all the sheets will calculate when the data on the main sheet changes.  But, it is doubtful, unless you have 100s of thousands of cells that are being referenced, one would notice.  Also there are formula that calculate every time a change is made, these are volatile functions and should be avoided if possible.

Comment: In this case all the various formulas will be based on just a single hardcoded date input (starting date). This input won't change. The formulas are all generic Excel built-in or of the simple +/-/multiply type. In that case do you know which approach would be preferable? Do you know if making the formulas in only one worksheet and referencing to the other worksheets leads to a lower or larger file size?

Comment: If they all route back to a single cell and none are volatile, then they will only calculate when that one cell changes.  I doubt you would notice any difference if they were on one sheet or multiple as far as speed goes.  As to size, well you should test that and see.